# MS SQL - converted extended austrian date to other date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'd like to convert date values in a Country specific Format.
Sample:

> Montag, 07. Jänner 2013 14:51:08

This is non-Standard German but Austrian.
I think it is no Problem to Exchange Austrian words into stardard German Terms (in this case: Januar)

I did not manage to convert this by using SQL command CONVERT, though it might be possible.

Desired date stlye is 2015-06-18

Comment: How are you storing and where are you showing the dates?

Comment: I do have a MS SQL Server (currently 2008 R2 / soon 2014). Currently I check the data by ordinary SELECT command to figure out how to convert. Then I will do an UPDATE on those values to replace them with the dates in desired style

Comment: Don't store the dates in anything but a `DateTime` typed column, that way you can control the formatting in your UI and the data itself is regional independent.

Comment: Is this `Montag, 07. Jänner 2013 14:51:08` how the dates are stored (meaning they are stored as varchar values), or how you want to display them?

Comment: thx - due to the application that works upon that SQL - the values are stored in varchar and will be in varchar after, too

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this: (warning, it's ugly)

Create a table for month names and numbers:

```
CREATE TABLE Months
(
   Month_Number char(2),
   Month_Name varchar(20)
)
```

Populate it with the months:

```
INSERT INTO Months VALUES
('01', 'Jänner'),
('02', 'Feber'),
('03', 'März'),
('04', 'April'),
('05', 'Mai'),
('06', 'Juni'),
('07', 'Juli'),
('08', 'August'),
('09', 'September'),
('10', 'Oktober'),
('11', 'November'),
('12', 'Dezember')
```

Now comes the ugly part: Use substring and patindex to create a standard date format:

```
DECLARE @StringDate varchar(50) = 'Montag, 07. Jänner 2013 14:51:08';

SELECT @StringDate As SourceDate,
       -- Year
       SUBSTRING(@StringDate, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %', @StringDate), 4) +'-'+
       -- Month
       Month_Number +'-'+
       -- Day
       SUBSTRING(@StringDate, PATINDEX('%, [0-3][0-9]. %', @StringDate) + 2, 2) +' '+
       -- Time
       SUBSTRING(@StringDate, PATINDEX('% [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]%', @StringDate) + 1, 8) As NormallyFormattedDate
FROM Months
WHERE Month_Name = SUBSTRING(@StringDate, PATINDEX('%, [0-3][0-9]. %', @StringDate)+6, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %', @StringDate) - (PATINDEX('%, [0-3][0-9]. %', @StringDate)+6))
```

Result:

```
SourceDate                                         NormallyFormattedDate
-------------------------------------------------- ---------------------
Montag, 07. Jänner 2013 14:51:08                   2013-01-07 14:51:08
```

Of course, this will only work if the format is the always the same(weekday, dd month. yyyy HH:mm:ss)